# Strange dips in sequence $u_n=\log{|(n-1)^{\text{st}}\text{ difference of first $n$ primes}|}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms

I made a sequence related to prime numbers.

In column A, I listed the sequence of prime numbers.
In column B, I listed the sequence of gaps between the prime numbers.
In column C, I listed the sequence of gaps between the terms of the previous sequence.
In column D, I listed the sequence of gaps between the terms of the previous sequence.
And so on.

[image]

I took the terms in the top diagonal (highlighted above; [A007442](https://oeis.org/A007442) and also [here](https://oeis.org/A007442/b007442.txt)), took the logs of their absolute values, and called this new sequence $u_n$.

Here is a graph of $u_n$ against $n$:

[image]

There are strange dips in the graph. The dips do not appear suddenly, but rather at the end of distinct arcs.

The coordinates of the first few dips are:
$(15, 6.10)$
$(27,14.27)$
$(39,20.98)$
$(48,27.84)$
$(98,63.25)$
$(112, 71.61)$

> Is there any explanation for this pattern?

Note that this kind of pattern is not unique to the sequence of prime numbers. The sequence of prime numbers is just a good example. Another example: in column A, I replaced the sequence of prime numbers with the digits in the decimal expansion of $e$ ([A001113](https://oeis.org/A001113)), and got the following graph, which also has dips:

[image]

It seems that, to produce a graph with dips, the sequence in column A must have some kind of irregularity.

Comment: What are the coordinates of the "dips"?

Comment: @JoshuaWang I have added some coordinates to the question.

Comment: Related: [A sequence derived from $\lceil \sin (2n) \rceil$ with some interesting features](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4738839/398708)